# Did the U.S. Army use a formula to evaluate fitness performance?

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle, pattern-recognition

While writing a web app to calculate one's score on the Army Physical Fitness Test (APFT), I grew tired of simply retyping this chart:

> [image]

I would like to know if there is an easier way to calculate a score such as a formula that might have been originally used. Is there a pattern or method to it?

I thought I got close with this, but no cigar:

$$((x*0.01)*71)*2$$

$x$ being the amount of reps a soldier completes and $71$ is the max needed for the youngest age group.

Comment: I think chances are good that these are percentiles from their actual data (perhaps normalized to some average that they want).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in each column they rounded a linear function. You get quite a good approximation already if you use the linear function defined by the first and last values in the column. I suspect that if you do a linear fit to the data in each column, rounding the result will reproduce the data.